# Looping through a DataTable to update Datetime values to Date values

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm using this loop but it has no effect - the date format stays the same. What is the correct syntax?

```
        Dim dt As DataTable
        Dim cellDate = DateTime.MinValue
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            For Each dc As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                dc.ReadOnly = False
                If row(dc) IsNot DBNull.Value Then
                    If DateTime.TryParse(row(dc), cellDate) Then
                        row(dc) = CDate(row(dc)).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
```

Comment: What does *update Datetime values to Date values* mean? What is the Type of those Columns? String or DateTime? What's the point of this: `row(dc) = CDate(row(dc)).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`? -- You know that a DateTime doesn't have a format, it's a number. Maybe you want to **present** the data using a specific format. Can you clarify the use of this code and the actual purpose?

Comment: @Jimi 17/02/2015 00:00:00 is being retrieved from a database and needs to become 17/02/2015 and so on

Comment: It's already like that. If the Column's Type is DateTime. Is it? Where do you want to show the data? Wherever that is, that's when you format a date in a specific way, for presentation.

Comment: @Jimi the data is being exported to a csv file. I suppose I can convert it when the data is being selected from the database to a varchar(10). It might save a lot of hassle.

Comment: You either export the data from the database directly, or use your DataTable, loop its Rows and format the DateTime Column when you generate a CSV record. Trying to impose a Format to something that doesn't have a format (a DateTime) is pointless. It becomes necessary when converting to string, possibly using an ISO format, not the very ambiguous `dd/MM/yyyy`.